# How to update an HTML table after writing form data to the spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a web page, which contains a form and an html table.

1. The user fills out the form;
2. Clicks on +;
3. A client side function prepares the data and have   `google.script.run.newTask(dataSet);` pass the data to the server-side
4. Another function gets it, makes a tweak or two and writes it to the spreadsheet;
5. Run another function that builds that HTML table, bringing the latest data just written

There are not errors, but the table is not built. Do I have to use `setTimeout()` or something that makes the last function wait for the previous ones to finish?

Here's the client side function:

```
function addTaskToSheet() {
  var formElements = document.getElementById("form").elements;
  var postData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++) {
    if (formElements[i].type != "submit" && formElements[i].type != 'checkbox') { //we dont want to include the submit-buttom
      postData.push(formElements[i].value);
    } else if (formElements[i].type == 'checkbox' && formElements[i].checked == true) {
      postData.push(formElements[i].checked);
    } else if (formElements[i].type == 'checkbox' && !formElements[i].checked) {
      postData.push('false');
    }
  }

  let timeStamp = new Date();
  timeStamp = timeStamp.toString();
  const agencyPartner = document.getElementById('agencySelect');
  const selectedAgency = agencyPartner.options[agencyPartner.selectedIndex].text;

  const client = document.getElementById('clientSelect');
  const selectedClient = client.options[client.selectedIndex].text;
  
  let dateAssigned = postData[1].toString();
  const item = postData[0];
  const link = postData[2];
  const notes = postData[3];
  const requestApproval = postData[4];

  let dataSet = [];
  dataSet.push(timeStamp, selectedAgency, selectedClient, '', '', dateAssigned, item, link, notes, '', requestApproval, '', '', '')
  console.log(dataSet)
  google.script.run.newTask(dataSet);
  setTimeout(loadClientTasks(selectedClient), 3000);
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `another function` of `Run another function that builds that HTML table, bringing the latest data just written` is `loadClientTasks`, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
google.script.run.newTask(dataSet);
setTimeout(loadClientTasks(selectedClient), 3000);
```

#### To:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(_ => loadClientTasks(selectedClient)).newTask(dataSet);
```

- By this modification, `loadClientTasks(selectedClient)` is run after `newTask(dataSet)` was finished.

#### Note:

- If you are required to use `setTimeout`, in the case of `setTimeout(loadClientTasks(selectedClient), 3000)`, `loadClientTasks` is run soon because of `(selectedClient)` of `loadClientTasks(selectedClient)`. In this case, how about the following modification?

  - To

    ```
      google.script.run.newTask(dataSet);
      setTimeout(loadClientTasks.bind(undefined, selectedClient), 3000);
    ```
  - or, if you are required to wait after `newTask` was finished, how about the following modification?

    ```
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(_ => setTimeout(loadClientTasks.bind(undefined, selectedClient), 3000)).newTask(dataSet);
    ```

#### Reference:

- [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))